# How many integers cannot be constructed as a sum of squares of distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Some numbers cannot be constructed from the sums of prime squares: 1,2,3 come to mind, since $2^2$ would be the smallest.

Using only prime squares, and using each one no more than once, is there a maximum integer which cannot be constructed this way, or are there infinitely many?

I'm aware of the four-squares theorem which says that any sufficiently large integer is the sum of four (possibly zero-valued) squares, and the two- and three-squares theorems which provide restrictions on what values will have such a representation, as well as the weak Goldbach result showing any number over $7$ (I think) is the sum of three primes. Unfortunately, none of that seems to directly apply to this question.

I did a little early checking, and if I'm right, only 15 out of the first 100 integers can be so represented, only 87 out of the first 400, and 317 out of the first 1000, which (unsurprisingly) suggests the ratio of representable numbers grows as your bound grows, but my gut suggests that there will turn out to be infinitely many, if increasingly sparsely distributed, non-representable numbers.

Worth mentioning that some numbers do have more than one representation, e.g. $410 = 11^2+17^2=7^2+19^2$.

Comment: Do you know this paper? <https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X10001101>

Comment: I didn't, thanks. Unfortunately, it's basically over my head, although the abstract seems to suggest that many/most numbers can be represented as the sum of three or four prime squares...

Comment: If you're allowed multiple uses, which I thought you meant from the title of your post, there are only finitely many numbers (in fact, 12 of them) that can't be written as a sum of squares of primes, because any sufficiently large number can be written as a sum of copies of $4 = 2^2$ and $9 = 3^2$.   See https://oeis.org/A078135.

Comment: see [OEIS A121518](https://oeis.org/A121518), there are 2438 numbers that cannot be written as sum of squares of distinct primes, the largest one is 17163.

Comment: @achillehui Is this list known to be complete ? Or is this just the beginning of the sequence ?

Comment: @Peter it is complete, I'm trying to locate an online copy of "Dressler, Robert E.; Pigno, Louis; Young, Robert
Sums of squares of primes.
Nordisk Mat. Tidskr. 24 (1976), no. 1, 39--40. " which should have a proof of this.

Comment: Can't locate a freely available copy of that paper, however I find this [page](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_242.htm) whose argument looks fine.